# Find a $95%$ confidence interval for $θ$ based on inverting the test statistic statistic $\hat{θ}$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval

So I am to define a 95% confidence interval for unknown parameter $θ$ by inverting the MLE of it.

For our data we have

$$Y_i \sim N(θx_i,1)  \quad \text{for} \quad   i=1,\ldots,n.$$

Therefore it can be proven that the MLE for $θ$ is given by

$$\hat{θ} = \frac{\sum x_i Y_i}{\sum x_i^2}$$

To find the confidence interval I should invert the test statistic $\hat{θ}$.

The most powerful unbiased size $α = 0,05$ test for testing

$$H_0: μ = μ_0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad   H_1: μ ≠ μ_0$$

where $X_1,\ldots,X_n ~ \text{ iid } n(μ,σ^2)$ has acceptance region

$$A(μ_0) = \left\{\mathbf{x}: |\bar{x} - μ_0| ≤ 1,96σ/\sqrt{n}\right\}.$$

Substituting my problem (I think) we get that the most powerful unbiased size $α = 0,05$ test for testing

$$H_0: θ = \hat{θ} \quad \text{vs.} \quad   H_1: θ ≠ \hat{θ}$$

has acceptance region

$$A(\hat{θ}) = \{\mathbf{y}: |\bar{y} - \hat{θ}| ≤ 1,96/\sqrt{n}\}$$

or equivalently,

$$A(\hat{θ}) = \left\{\mathbf{y}: \frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{y} - 1,96}{\sqrt{n}x_i} ≤ \hat{θ} ≤ \frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{y} + 1,96}{\sqrt{n}x_i} \right\}$$

Substituting $\hat{θ} = \sum x_iYi/\sum x_i^2$ we obtain

$$A(\hat{θ}) = \left\{\mathbf{y}: \frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{y} - 1,96}{\sqrt{n}x_i} ≤ \frac{Σx_iYi}{Σx_i^2} ≤ \dfrac{\sqrt{n}\bar{y} + 1,96}{\sqrt{n}x_i}\right\}$$

This means that my $1 - 0,05 = 0,95$ (95%) confindence interval is defined to be

$$ C(y) = \{\hat{θ}: y ∈ A(\hat{θ})\}$$

But I can't seem to find anything concrete and I feel that I've made mistakes somewhere. What to do?

Reference for the question: http://people.unica.it/musio/files/2008/10/Casella-Berger.pdf (Section 9.2.1)

Comment: You wrote about "The most powerful unbiased size $α = 0,05$ test for testing $H_0: μ = μ_0$ vs. $H_1: μ ≠ μ_0$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_n ~ \text{ iid } n(μ,σ^2)$".  But that is not the situation you have here.  The expected values are not all equal. $\qquad$

Comment: Should I change the form of the entire test or just the acceptance region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
\widehat \theta = \frac{\sum_i x_i Y_i}{\sum_i x_i^2}.
$$
Although non-linear in $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, this is linear in $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$, and that's why it's a "linear" model (it's **not** because one is fitting a straight line; if that were true then least-squares fitting of polynomials would be considered non-linear regression, but it's linear regression).  So you have a linear combination of independent normally distributed random variables, where the coefficients are constant (i.e. not random). Being a linear combination of independent normally distributed random variables with constant coefficients makes its distribution easy to find:
\begin{align}
\widehat\theta \sim N\left( \frac{\sum_i (x_i \operatorname{E}(Y_i))}{\sum_i x_i^2} , \frac{\sum_i \big(x_i^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i)\big)}{\left( \sum_i x_i^2 \right)^2}  \right) & = N \left( \theta, \frac 1 {\sum_i x_i^2} \right) \\ &  \text{since } \operatorname{E}(Y_i) = x_i\theta \text{ and } \operatorname{var}(Y_i) = 1.
\end{align}

So
$$
\Pr \left( \theta - A \frac 1 {\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}} < \widehat\theta < \theta + A \frac 1 {\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}} \right) = 0.95
$$
where $A$ is such that $\Pr( -A<Z<A ) = 0.95$.
Consequently
$$
\Pr \left( \widehat \theta - A \frac 1 {\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}} < \theta < \widehat \theta + A \frac 1 {\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}} \right) = 0.95
$$
and that is your confidence interval.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did you mean $dfrac{(∑_ix_i)^2var(Y_i)}{(∑_ix_i^2)^2$ as the variance of $hat{\theta}$?

Comment: Yes. If $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent then the variance of $c_1 Y_1 + \cdots + c_n Y_n$, where $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are constant (i.e. not random) is $c_1^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_1) + \cdots + c_n^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_n). \qquad$

Comment: Sorry I mean did you mean $\dfrac{(∑_ix_i)^2\text{var}(Y_i)}{(∑_ix_i^2)^2}$ instead of $\dfrac{∑_ix_i^2\text{var}(Y_i)}{(∑_ix_i^2)^2}$ for $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: It is NOT $\dfrac{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i)}{(\sum_i x_i^2)^2}.$ It is $\dfrac{\sum_i x_i^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i)}{\left(\sum_i x_i^2 \right)^2}. \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and I would ask what the expression $\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i)$ means.  What if $n=3$?  Then it would be $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i),$ and what value would the subscript $i$ have in $Y_i$?  Would $i$ be $1$, or $2$, or $3$? $\qquad$

Comment: Oops! I see that would have been unuseful, thanks!